# gdal resize and save to png using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, gis, gdal, image-registration

I know how to use gdal_translate from cmd line to resize and save the png:

```
gdal_translate -of PNG -outsize 10% 10% image.bsq image.png
```

But using python I only know how to save the png:

```
from osgeo import gdal

img_png  = 'image.png'
img_bsq  = 'image.bsq'
src_ds = gdal.Open(img_bsq)
out_format = "GTiff"
driver = gdal.GetDriverByName(out_format)
dst_ds = driver.CreateCopy(img_png, dst_ds, 0)
dst_ds = None
src_ds = None
```

May I ask how to resize and save the png using python?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `gdal_translate` in python. Something like this should work.

```
from osgeo import gdal

options_list = [
    '-outsize 10% 10%',
    '-of PNG'
] 
options_string = " ".join(options_list)

gdal.Translate('image.png',
               'image.bsq',
               options=options_string)
```

You could of course also write the options string yourself if you like, however i like to write it as a list and then convert it.

If you are not comfortable with the python bindings, you can also use `subprocess` or `os.system` to call the command line versions.